# Existential Notation: Is "$\exists mn$" the same as "$\exists m\exists n$"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, quantifiers

I'm doing an exercise for Discrete Mathematics, chapter Logic, topic Quantifiers. However, I never seen this kind of notation: "$\exists mn$".

Is "$\exists mn$" same as "$\exists m \exists n$"?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $\exists\,m,n:\cdots$ is used and equivalent to $\exists\, m:\exists\, n:\cdots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is "$\exists mn$" same as "$\exists m \exists n$"?

Yes, exactly. This is just a shorthand / abbreviation. If you want to be completely formal about it, you would write out $\exists m \; \exists n$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is because $\exists m, \exists n, P(m,n)$  is true if and only if $\exists n, \exists m, P(m,n).$  So you can think of $\{m,n\}$ as a block variable where order does not matter and instead write $\exists \{m,n\}, P(m,n)$ or informally $\exists m,n, P(m,n).$